# Prove that the sequence $(_)$ defined below converges, and find its limit $_1= 2, _{n+1} = \frac{2}{1 + _n}$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

I tried to use the MCT monotone convergence theorem but it failed since it is not monotone. So I’m not sure how to prove that it convergence, I thought about using Cauchy definition. I found that the limit is -2 and 1 but I’m not sure which one to select since it is not monotone which value it converges to.

Comment: Would you like to have the question in your question ***body***? (Also it is not clear whether the series is $x_{n+1}=\frac 2 {1+x_n}$ or $x_{n+1}=\frac 2 1+x_n$ (or something else))

Comment: I'm guessing you don't mean $x_n + 1 = \frac{2}{1} + x_n$? Please format your question with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), or failing that, at least use parentheses to make the question clear.

Comment: (The limit is certainly going to be no less than zero if exists, as all $x_i\gt 0$)

Comment: $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$ are monotonic

Comment: Hint: let $y_n = \frac{x_n - 1}{x_n + 2}$, it satisfy a much similar recurrence relation $y_{n+1} = -\frac{y_n}{2}$.

Comment: $x_{n+2}-1=(x_n-1)/(3+x_n)$

Comment: But I need to show that the sequence converges.

Answer (score 4):

Claim:
$$
x_n =\frac{2^{n+1}+2(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^n}
$$
For $n=1$, we have $x_1=6/3=2$. Further,
$$
x_{n+1} (1+x_n)= \frac{2^{n+2}+2(-1)^{n}}{2^{n+2}+(-1)^{n+1}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{2^{n+1}+2(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^n}\right )=2
$$This clearly gives $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let X=$$\begin{array}{l}\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\frac{2}{1+\frac{2}{1+\frac{2}{...\infty}}}\end{array}$$

Implies X=2/(1+x)

X^2+X-2=0

(X+2)(X-1)=0

Since X is obviously>0

X=1

Comment: I wonder how you can show that the sequence even converges?

Comment: Cant we express the roots of a quadratic as a infinitely continued fraction?

Comment: Sorry if im wrong btw

Comment: Well, so your assumption (as I see) is that the sequence converges, then this is certainly correct. But what if the sequence diverges?

Comment: the roots are equivalent to the continued fraction right?

Comment: so if one of them is finite the other must be as well

Comment: again im sorry if im making an embarassing mistake

Comment: I am still not sure how to prove it convergence since the monotone convergence theorem fails.

Answer (score 0):

if $x_{n}$ has limit, so does $x_{n+1}$. Let's denote $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = a \Rightarrow a = \frac{2}{1+a} \Rightarrow a^2 + a - 2 = 0$. The roots of this equation are 1 and -2, but -2 can't be the limit, because $x_{n} > 0 \ \forall n$, thus $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = 1$

Comment: This doesn't show that the sequence converges.